# FxCop static code analysis .dll can be loaded for .NET

Tags: .net, jenkins

I am using .NET framework 4.5, FxCop 10, Jenkins 1.609.

I am trying to set static code analysis for .NET code. I refer from [FAKE](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/gettingstarted.html) and set all environment. It's working fine for same project mention in referenced link.

Now I added my project and found that some of .dll can not be loaded because of following reason :

`<Exception Keyword="CA0055" Kind="AssemblyLoad">
   <Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Common.AssemblyLoadException</Type>
   <ExceptionMessage>Could not load BCSProducts.dll.</ExceptionMessage>
   <InnerType>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FxCopException</InnerType>
   <InnerExceptionMessage>The first successfully loaded assembly for this project was linked against v2.0.50727. 'BCSProducts' was linked against v4.0.30319 and so cannot be analyzed from within the same project.</InnerExceptionMessage>
   <InnerStackTrace>   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.IntrospectionAnalysisEngine.CanLoadTargetFile(TargetFile target)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Common.EngineManager.LoadTargets(TargetFile target, Boolean resetCounts, String loadEngine)</InnerStackTrace>
  </Exception>`

I don't know what does this even mean. But I tried so many solutions by none of those are working,

Comment: You are using a very old version of FxCop, it cannot handle .NET 4 assemblies.  This is the kind of misery you get into when you try to avoid paying for a VS license on a build server.  Invariably turns quickly from penny-wise into pound-foolish.  The Community edition is free, I think it supports code analysis.

Comment: @HansPassant, is there anyway I can export code analysis report from VS to CI server. Setting up code analysis on Jenkins is custom requirement. How can I know code analysis reports  from developer VS before merge?

Comment: ps : I am upgrading FxCop 10, although in GUI it says this is latest version, but I think FxCop 14 is latest available,.

Comment: I upgrade FxCop to 14, and getting this error : 

"The following error was encountered while reading module 'BCSProducts': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

1. Microsoft remove support after FxCop 10. They only provide support for standalone version available for visual studio.
2. Visual studio provides static code analysis, and they uses FxCop in backend. Which is Version 14 available.
3. You can not analyze framework 4.5 code with FxCop 10. You have to use visual studio FxCop version 14.0
4. We can use it just by giving path of visual studio plugin as display in screen. [image]
5. Just set source dll/exe and set result xml in violations and you are good to go.